# Getting a routing error trying to call a DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem calling a `DELETE` query on the right route

This is the route I want to query the `DELETE`

```
post_comment DELETE (/:locale)/*category/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)
```

This is the link that SHOULD trigger the `DELETE` on the right route:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("bin_icon.png",:size => "65x35"), 
            post_comment_path(id: comment.id, 
                              post_id: comment.post_id,
                              category: comment.category),
            method: 'delete',
            class: 'edit-links' %>
```

It is in a partial called `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` which is rendered inside of `app/views/comments/index.html.erb`

The error I get is a simple routing error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/de/general/announcements/posts/21/comments"
```

**What I have tried also:**

```
<%= link_to image_tag("bin_icon.png",:size => "65x35"), 
            comment,
            method: 'delete',
            class: 'edit-links' %>
```

Because his is what works in my user views:

```
<%= link_to t('delete'),
            user,
            method: :delete,
            class: 'delete-button' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now:

This is how you adress it: all url params in the right order for example:

```
post_comment_path(comment.category, @post, comment)
```

Or is my case also like this:

```
post_comment_path(category: comment.category, id: comment.id)
```

Allthough I dont understand why my first approach of passing the `:post_id` params manually into the helper didnt generate me the right route.

It was just putting the `id`of the comment `21` as `/:post_id/` instead of `/:id` and set `/:id` to nil at the end of the url in this route:

```
post_comment DELETE (/:locale)/*category/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)
```

resulting in this route:

```
/posts/21/comments/
```

instead of for example:

```
/posts/2/comments/21
```

I am a bit confused why this happens but it is working for now like it should have in the beginning.